# How to show this big O equality.

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform

Let $R(x) = P (x)/Q(x)$ be a rational function with $(\text{degree}\: Q)≥ (\text{degree}\: P )+2$ and $Q(x) \not= 0$ on the real axis. Then I want to prove that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}R(x) e^{-2 \pi i x ξ}dx=O(e^{-a|ξ|})$$

and determine the best possibles $a's$  in terms of the roots of $Q$.

I know that if $α_1 , . . . , α_k$ are the roots of Q in the upper half-plane, then there exists polynomials $P_j(ξ)$ of degree less than the multiplicity of $α_j$ so that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}R(x) e^{-2 \pi i x ξ}dx= \sum_{j=1}^k P_j(ξ)e^{-2 \pi i \alpha_j ξ}$$

with $ξ<0$ and in the case $ξ>0$ we have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}R(x) e^{-2 \pi i x ξ}dx= \sum_{j=1}^{l} H_j(ξ)e^{2 \pi i \beta_j ξ}$$

now the $\beta_j$ are the roots but in the lower half plane. But I don't know how to use this to prove an inequality in the integral.The first thing I've got is that I have to prove that

$$\sum_{j=1}^k |P_j(ξ)e^{-2 \pi i \alpha_j ξ}|< M_1e^{-a|ξ|},\;\;\; \xi < 0$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{l} |H_{j}(ξ)e^{2 \pi i \beta_j ξ}|< M_2e^{-a|ξ|},\;\;\; \xi > 0$$

So I have to bound the function $ξ^n e^{-c|ξ|}$ or prove that $ξ^n e^{-c|ξ|}=O(e^{-c|ξ|})$ but I don't know how to do that and determine the best possibles $a's$

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In the first sentence of the second paragraph: "are the roots of R" should read "are the poles of R" or "are the roots of Q". Zeros don't allow you to evaluate. Poles do. And you need to make the assumption that you don't have any poles on the real axis.

Comment: Sorry :) right, let me change it :)

Comment: You're now using $P$ in two ways. I suggest using $H$ and $K$ for the coefficients on the right. And you need to note that the $H$ and $K$ are polynomials.

Comment: Hahahaha right I have some typos there just a second

Comment: Where as you pointed out in the other question we have the evaluation of some polynomials and $ξ$ is to the nth power :)

Comment: Is that correct or what is the correction you are saying ?

Comment: You can't put the two expressions together without something else because the one expression holds for $\xi > 0$ and the other for $\xi < 0$. Both expressions decay in their respective regimes.

Comment: Right but then do we have to do this by cases ?

Comment: Either your expression is correct or it is not. As it stands, it is not correct. You're adding two functions that are not defined on the same domain. In fact the intersection of their domains is empty!

Comment: Just a second :)

Comment: Ready hope this is correct :)

Comment: I've changed your notation to distinguish the roots in the upper and lower half planes, as well as the number of those roots.

Comment: Right :) that looks better :)

Comment: Then what can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing exclusively with expressions of a real variable $\xi$. Every continuous function on a closed, bounded interval has a maximum value. For a fixe $r > 0$, the expression $f(x)=|x|^{n}e^{-r|x|}$ tends to $0$ as $r\rightarrow\pm\infty$:
\begin{align}
       \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{-rx}x^{n} & =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^{rx}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(-r)e^{rx}} \\
   & = \cdots = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{(-r)^{n}e^{rx}} = 0.
\end{align}
Therefore, you can choosen $X > 0$ such that $|e^{-rx}x^{n}| < 1$ whenever $x > X$. If you then find the maximum of $|e^{-rx}x^{n}|$ on $[0,2X]$--let's say that maximum is $M$--then $|e^{-rx}x^n| \le \max\{M,1\}$. So there exists a positive constant $C_{r,n}$ such that
$$
                          |e^{-r|x|}x^{n}| \le C_{r,n},\;\;\; 
$$
Therefore, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$, then there is a constant $C_{r,p}$ such that
$$
                      |p(x)e^{-r|x|}| \le C_{r,n}
$$
If $a > 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$ with $\epsilon < a$, then
$$
             |p(x)e^{-a|x|}| = |p(x)e^{-\epsilon|x|}|e^{-(r-\epsilon)|x|}
      \le C_{\epsilon,p}e^{-(r-\epsilon)|x|}
$$
You can't do any better than that. You an get a bound in terms of an exponent that is as close as you want to $a$, but you cannot get a bound using $a$ on the right instead of $a-\epsilon$. If you could, you would reach the contradiction that $|p(x)| \le C$ for some $C$. What happens is that as you take smaller and smaller values of $\epsilon$, the constant $C_{\epsilon,p}$ must be taken to be larger and larger. So you're not going to find a perfect bound--it's a little bit of a juggling act between $e^{-(r-\epsilon)|x|}$ and the constant $C_{\epsilon,p}$.

In your case, you have several different exponents to consider. In the case where $\xi < 0$, you must consider the roots $\alpha_j$ of $Q$ that are in the upper half plane, where the imaginary part satisfies $\Im\alpha_j > 0$.
\begin{align}
 |\exp\{-2\pi i\alpha_j \xi\}| & = |\exp\{ -2\pi i(\Re\alpha_j+i\Im\alpha_j)\xi\}| \\
  & = |\exp\{2\pi\Im\alpha_j\xi\}| = e^{-2\pi\Im\alpha_j|\xi|}
\end{align}
If you let $a = 2\pi\min\{\Im\alpha_1,\Im\alpha_2,\cdots,\Im\alpha_k\}$, then
$|e^{-2\pi i\alpha_j\xi}| \le e^{-a|\xi|}$ for $1 \le j \le k$ and for all $\xi$. Then you can combine these bounds with the bounds of the previous paragraph to get what you want for any $a$ strictly less than the minimum of $\Im\alpha_j$ for $1\le j \le k$ and less than the minimum of $-\Im\beta_j$ for $1 \le j \le l$.

Comment: Let me check it just give me some time right? :)

Comment: @user162343 : If you like an answer, you can +1 it with the arrow and/or accept it with a checkmark.

Comment: Right, the thing is that I want to check it carefully and if I accept your answer I won't be able to ask you questions about it :)

Comment: Does this work for both expressions in the post?

Comment: I mean does your answer works with $\xi >0$

Comment: @user162343 : You can check that it does. The absolute value in the exponent is what makes it work in either case.

Comment: good, then this will be the complete proof for both questions right?

Comment: @user162343 : Yes. Of course the other question contained a part of the question about correctness. There I explained that the problem as stated was not correct. The correctly stated problem has solution as given here in  this problem.

Comment: Yes of course but I was asking about the best possibles a's in terms of the roots of $Q$ :)

Comment: @user162343 : You can't get a best possible exponent. That was part of my explanation. You can use any exponent up to, but not including, the absolute value of the smallest imaginary part of the root of the denominator closest to the real axis, but you can't get an estimate of the stated form using that endpoint case.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part of your comment :)

Comment: If the roots of the denominator are $\alpha_j$ with $r = \min_{j}\{|\Im\alpha_j|\}$, then you an estimate bounded by $C_{r'}e^{-r'|\xi|}$ for any $0 < r' < r$, but you can't get an estimate of that form with $r'=r$.

Comment: Ok let me check it again but before that, can you help me with this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720960/how-to-prove-this-equality ? Of course if you agree